# Sumar dos input y restarlos al total con jquery

Tags: jquery, entrada

Tengo una ventana para el carrito de compras con dos input, uno donde escribo el total cobrado con tarjeta de credito o debito, y otro para el pago en efectivo contado.
sucede que el cliente en una compra puede usar los dos metodos a la vez. Entonces quiero que al escribir en cualquiera de los dos se sume automaticamente con el otro si es distinto de vacio.
Pero a la vez quiero que la suma se reste al total de la factura y que se muestre el vuelto digamos(lo que hay que darle al cliente) en otro input.

Hice lo siguiente pero no funciona:

```js
$("#efectivo").keyup(function(){
    efectivo=$("#efectivo").val();
 if (efectivo===""){ 
     if ($("#Tarjeta").val()!==""){
    tarjeta = $("#Tarjeta").val();
    vuelto = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(tarjeta);
    $("#Vuelto").val(vuelto);
    }
    }else
    
   if ($("#efectivo").val!==""){ 
   
            if (total!==0){
    
             var efectivo = $("#efectivo").val();
            if ($("#Tarjeta").val()!==""){
        
                    tarjeta = $("#Tarjeta").val();
    
                                        }
                    var entrego = parseFloat(efectivo) + parseFloat(tarjeta);
    
                    vuelto = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(entrego);

                    $("#Vuelto").val(vuelto);
                            }
   
   }
    
});

$("#Tarjeta").keyup(function(){
    tarjeta=$("#Tarjeta").val();
 if (tarjeta===""){ 
     if ($("#efectivo").val()!==""){
    efectivo = $("#efectivo").val();
    vuelto = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(efectivo);
    $("#Vuelto").val(vuelto);
    }
    }else
    
   if ($("#Tarjeta").val!==""){ 
   
            if (total!==0){
    
             var tarjeta = $("#Tarjeta").val();
            if ($("#efectivo").val()!==""){
        
                    efectivo = $("#efectivo").val();
    
                                        }
                    var entrego = parseFloat(efectivo) + parseFloat(tarjeta);
    
                    vuelto = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(entrego);

                    $("#Vuelto").val(vuelto);
                            }
   
   }
    

});
```

Alguna sugerencia?Este es el html de los campos:

```html
<div class="row">


<label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contado/Efectivo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="efectivo" placeholder="Dinero en efectivo"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Efectivo Banco</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Tarjeta" placeholder="Tarjeta"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vuelto</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Vuelto" placeholder="Vuelto"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: Si como no. lo acabo de poner estan los 3 inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si inicializas tus variables, tu codigo aunque no es optimo funciona:

```js
var total = 264;
var efectivo = 0;
var tarjeta = 0;
$("#efectivo").keyup(function(){
    efectivo=$("#efectivo").val();
 if (efectivo===""){ 
     if ($("#Tarjeta").val()!=""){
      tarjeta = $("#Tarjeta").val();
      vuelto = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(tarjeta);
      $("#Vuelto").val(vuelto);
    }
 }else
    
   if ($("#efectivo").val!==""){ 
   
            if (total!==0){
    
             var efectivo = $("#efectivo").val();
            if ($("#Tarjeta").val()!=""){
          
                    tarjeta = $("#Tarjeta").val();
                    console.log(tarjeta);
                                        }
                    var entrego = parseFloat(efectivo) + parseFloat(tarjeta);
    
                    vuelto = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(entrego);

                    $("#Vuelto").val(vuelto);
                            }
   
   }
    
});

$("#Tarjeta").keyup(function(){
    tarjeta=$("#Tarjeta").val();
 if (tarjeta===""){ 
     if ($("#efectivo").val()!==""){
    efectivo = $("#efectivo").val();
    vuelto = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(efectivo);
    $("#Vuelto").val(vuelto);
    }
    }else
    
   if ($("#Tarjeta").val!==""){ 
   
            if (total!==0){
    
             var tarjeta = $("#Tarjeta").val();
            if ($("#efectivo").val()!==""){
        
                    efectivo = $("#efectivo").val();
    
                                        }
                    var entrego = parseFloat(efectivo) + parseFloat(tarjeta);
    
                    vuelto = parseFloat(total) - parseFloat(entrego);

                    $("#Vuelto").val(vuelto);
                            }
   
   }
    

});
```

```html
<div class="row">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label  class="col-sm-2 control-label">Contado/Efectivo</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="efectivo" placeholder="Dinero en efectivo"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Efectivo Banco</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Tarjeta" placeholder="Tarjeta"/>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Vuelto</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Vuelto" placeholder="Vuelto"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo por tu ayuda